# MySQL - Best practice to cross two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have two tables. Each one is populated with about 50K records. Both have one common field. I want the records of both tables where the common field is matching. So I use the following SQL code. The problem is that the query is running now for already 20 minutes and nothing happening. It seems strange to me that it is taking so much time. I wonder if there is a better way to achieve my target. Thank you in advance for your replies.

My SQL code:

```
Select * from tableOne T1, tableTwo T2 
Where T1.name = T2.name
```

By the way I am open to php solutions (loops or whatever if it is better...)

Comment: I guess you could also show us the ddl + indexes of the 2 tables :-)

Comment: Your tables probably aren't indexed correctly.

Comment: The _best_ practice is to use `inner join`, although that wouldn't be the cause of failure here. Why is MySQL at the title, but not at the tags? Could you provide more context on how you are using it?

Comment: Best practice is to include the output of EXPLAIN $your_query when asking questions of this type. (and learn how to interpret EXPLAIN yourself). How you join the two tables has nothing to do with best prctice (as long as it is done in the database - but is relevant to what result you get)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. You need to make sure there is an index on the *name* column in both tables.  Otherwise the query will have to essentially scan every row of each table looking for matches.
2. Ideally, the index should have "included columns" that you want to select in the query.  Otherwise the query won't be able to fully use the index, but will have to go back to the table and pick up the other columns manually for each row.  This means you should consider selecting only the columns you need (rather than *) in the query, and adding those columns as included columns to the index.

Comment: Hello. When I hear index I think of primary key and unique indexes to avoid duplicates. This is all i know about indexes. Are you talking about the same think? Can I set those in PHP My Admin. Thanks...

Comment: @Marc: There are 4 types of indexes.  `PRIMARY KEY`, `UNIQUE`, `INDEX`, and `FULLTEXT`.  When looking at your table's structure in phpMyAdmin, click the "index" button (looks like a yellow lightning bolt) next to the field, in this case "name".  `INDEX`es are used to help MySQL search/sort tables.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: Yes, just an *Index* is the one you want.  It's not a primary or unique key, but purely meant to facilitate queries against the column(s) it contains.

Comment: So I add an index on the two fields that are common bewteen my two tables I try to cross?

Comment: Great !!! That made the trick. My query has been executed in the fraction of a second after putting index on the two common fields. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select *
from tableOne t1
inner join tableTwo t2 on t1.name = t2.name
```

Althought I doubt that would make a difference, trying won't hurt. It's not recommended to use 
`from tableOne t1, tableTwo t2`, because you are implicitly making a cartesian product!

Comment: `from tableOne T1, tableTwo T2 where T1.name = T2.name` is the same as `INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.name = t2.name`.

Comment: Yes, I know, that's why I've said 'trying won't hurt'. We need more context because hanging with 50k records is ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's better to use [Join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableOne
INNER JOIN TableTwo
ON tableOne.name=TableTwo.name
```

Comment: Hello eric. What I am doing and using inner join seems to be pretty much the same in terms of performance...

Comment: I don't think such a long time to execute query is valid. are you trying it via PHP or running the query on the server? if it's via PHP maybe something has gone wrong...

Comment: `from tableOne T1, tableTwo T2 where T1.name = T2.name` is the same as `INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.name = t2.name`.

Answer (score 0):

Should be an inner join to get rows that join on name from both tables.

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.name = t2.name
```

Comment: `from tableOne T1, tableTwo T2 where T1.name = T2.name` is the same as `INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.name = t2.name`.

Comment: Then it's an index problem. Add an INDEX to name as another commenter suggested. Your syntax is not ANSI SQL.

Comment: I think the `FROM table1,table2` is a MySQL specific extension.

Comment: Don't use db-specific syntax for SQL, bad idea, but not related to your problem.

Comment: If you never have to support other dbs, then it shouldn't matter.  I love me some `REPLACE INTO` and `JOIN...USING()`. :-P

Comment: As you progress through your career (if this indeed is your career) then you will not be able to avoid encountering various DB vendors (postgres, sql server, oracle) and you will be best served learning standard SQL syntax. Trust me. Been there, done it, for many years.

Comment: I agree, I guess I'm just spoiled my MySQL.

Comment: Also, it's better to join on numeric indexes, even though adding an index to a varchar will speed things up. You should normalize your string set into a table like [ 1 | Foo, 2 | Bar ] and then in your 2 tables use the index on that table. If you really needed to use the string representation for the join then you could join this meta table into the mix and add it to the WHERE. Anyway ...

Comment: Thanks guys for the advices... Solved my problem with the help of dbaseman

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Inner Joins - what you have happening there - are very efficient. 50K records is not very much at all, and twenty minutes is ridiculously long even for a pair of tables with a couple million entries. Try to restart the query, or just restart the whole web server. The query itself if fine (although it's good practice to specify exact which columns from each table you want, even if you want every column except one). Adding an index if you don't have one is also a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

What is your tables' storage engine? If it is InnoDB, you would need to set a foreign key between these two tables -- that will definitely solve your performance problem.